# About the properties of Lebesgue measurable subsets

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, vector-analysis

This is a doubt about Lebesgue measurable subsets

If I have  two Lebesgue measurable subsets $E_1, E_2$ in $\mathbb{R}$, is the subset $E_1\times E_2$ Lebesgue measurable in $\mathbb{R}^2$?, If it is, How can I compute $|E_1\times E_2|_2$?

Comment: Yes and $|E_1\times E_2|=|E_1||E_2|$

Answer (score 1):

Yes and it is more general, indeed it holds for $\mathbb{R}^n$.
[Here](http://www.math.umn.edu/~jodeit/course/Thm5.1.pdf) you can find the proof.
For the second question I quote @leo.